# Gimbal Lock Problem while rotating around 3 axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do rotation on all of the 3 axes. I have three buttons for each axis, say user pressed X. Then the object should return 90 degrees around X axis. But looks like I cannot get rid of the gimbal lock situation whatever I do. Now I have

```
private void rotateMe()
{
    if (x)
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    else if (y)
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    else if (z)
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
}
```

This too still gives me gimbal lock problem. How do I get rid of the gimbal lock problem?

Comment: if you are using quaternions there is no way a gimbal lock can happen. There must be another error in your code.

Comment: Yes, it turns out something different were causing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally no expert for `Quaternion` so if you want to use them rather stick to whatever [Ruzihm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59711596/7111561) says ;)

---

However in your case I would suggest to rather simply directly go through the `Transform` component and not even think about `Quaternion` using [`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) or [`transform.RotateArround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

```
private void rotateMe()
{
    Vector3 axis;
    if (x) axis = Vector3.right;
    else if (y) axis = Vector3.up;
    else if (z) axis = Vector3.forward;

    if(Mathf.Approximately(axis.magnitude, 0)) return;

    transform.Rotate(axis, 90, Space.World);
}
```

**Note:** There is the optional parameter `Space relativeTo` for `Rotate`! By default it is `Space.Self` so it uses the objects own local coordinate system, which is rotated after doing the rotation! So you might rather always want to rotate using the world space axis.

---

A second thought: Is it possible that what you get here is no "gimbal lock" but you don't reset `x`, `y` and `z` correctly so they stay always `true` → always jumps into the first case? Make sure you reset them somewhere e.g. directly after rotating

```
private void rotateMe()
{
    Vector3 axis;
    if (x) axis = Vector3.right;
    else if (y) axis = Vector3.up;
    else if (z) axis = Vector3.forward;

    if(Mathf.Approximately(axis.magnitude, 0)) return;

    transform.Rotate(axis, 90, Space.World);

    x = false;
    y = false;
    z = false;
}
```

depends of course if you need them somewhere else or not but we would need to see more code to answer this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm afraid this didn't solve my problem either. It still locks to rotating around X axis.

Comment: did you make sure you reset `x`, `y` and `z` somewhere? maybe it is always `true` so always jumps into that case?

Comment: A function from a different script sends x, y, z to the script with rotateMe() with every button click. I checked my parameters and they seem ok. But I'll do debugging anyways and see if the rotation values are sent alright.

Comment: Ok it would really help to see the whole rotation script then ... I guess you could avoid some trouble by rather passing an enum like `public enum RotateAxis { x, y, z }` instead of multiple bools. Is there no way for you to call the method directly as a `public void rotateMe(RotateAxis rotateAxis)` instead?

Comment: Hugo (assuming its your name), I'm such an idiot! Some values I use were stuck because I didn't reset them after the rotation! I will never trust my code this much ever again! :D Thank you for your help, I wouldn't check if you didn't give me a heads up.

Comment: @GünseliÖzkan it's only my username ;) But your welcome! We all make these mistakes from time to time, that's why it was directly my second thought that this might be the case here => don't be to hard to yourself ;) with more practice you'll get better in general coding style. And sometimes still you just need some second pair of eyes ;)

Comment: Great answer, and good job figuring out asker's real problem lol. BTW, you may rather do `if  (Mathf.Approximately(axis.sqrMagnitude, 0)) return;` to avoid a square root calculation ;).  `if (axis == Vector3.zero) return;` should also work, because Unity does approximate comparisons of `Vector3`, but it may be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your complaint is that it's using the local axes instead of world axes:

Use `Y = A * X` to get the rotation Y after rotating by X then by A, but by the axes prior to X's rotation. This should get the result you want:

```
private void rotateMe(){
    if (x)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.right) * transform.rotation;
    else if (y)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up) * transform.rotation;
    else if (z)
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.forward) * transform.rotation;
}
```

Comment: I'm probably confused (as usual for Quaternion ^^) but I thought the order of rotation was already correct since you want to rotate first the current rotation then the addition?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick answer! Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. After rotating a couple times, the rotation locks. No matter which axis I turn, it just keeps doing the same fixed rotation.

Comment: @derHugo this answer is equivalent to the first part of your answer ;)

Comment: @GünseliÖzkan this doesn't gimbal lock, but I see the problem was actually caused by something you didn't share in the question. This is why we ask that you include a [mre] in the question.

Comment: @Ruzihm oh okey ^^ Yeah I avoid `Quaternion` wherever I can lol ^^